# pasar palabras de una linea de txt a lista

Tags: python, tkinter

imagen que hay un txt  como el siguiente:

```
juan pepe 123 25 345
marcelo velasquez 345 45 566
```

donde `juan pepe, 123,25,345` son elementos de una lista llamada usuario1, que a su vez esta pertenece a una lista llamadas usuario.

¿alguna idea de como podria hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Para leer el archivo y  asignarlas a una [lista](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-list), sería haciendo uso del método [Readlines](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readlines.htm) El **valor devuelto es justamente Una Lista** *(una opción)*

```
nombrearchivo = "file.txt"
contenido=[]
with open(nombrearchivo) as dr:
    contenido = fdr.readlines()
#Comprobar Contenido Extraído
print contenido
```

**Update** Elementos individuales de la lista. usando el método [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) *(tomando como ejemplo que sus valores están separados por un espacio)*

```
nombrearchivo = "file.txt"
contenido=[]

with open(nombrearchivo) as fin:
    contenido = [ linea.strip().split(' ') for linea in fin ]
print contenido
```

Comment: Gracias Joel, imagino que se agregara toda la linea completa "juan pepe 123 25 345" como una cadena, luego la siguiente linea como otra cadena, o me equivoco?, en tal caso habria una forma de agregar las palabras de la cadena como elementos individuales?

Comment: Así es , el primer ejemplo estaba apuntando a esa solución. actualicé mi respuesta tomando en cuenta su comentario. espero pueda ayudar.